# Return the result of a mongoose model function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm working on a Restful API with node.js and mongoose. I need to return an object with the results of a search. Here is my code:

```
var Get = function (criteria) {      
    var result;
    Users.findOne(criteria, function(err, res){
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        console.log('Results: ' + res);
        result = err || !res ? err || errors['404']: res;
        console.log(result);
    });
    console.log('Final results: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
};
```

Since I was having problems, I added those console.logs to watch where the result is lost. Here are the logs:

`Final results: undefined
Error: null
Results: { //user... }`

I need that result to be returned. How can I solve this?

Comment: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Note: A future possible option will be using [`await`](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) with functions that use [ES6 `Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), provided MongoDB's client API begins using those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most asked questions in the history of the internet!

Since node is asynchronous you'll need to rewrite the function to return a callback or use something like promises.

Here it is with callbacks:

```
var Get = function (criteria, cb) {      
    return Users.findOne(criteria,cb);  
};
```

And then call it like:

```
Get({}, function(err, res){
  console.log(res);
});
```

Or you can use promises, here it is using the Q library

```
var Get = function (criteria) {   

var deferred = Q.defer();
 Users.findOne(criteria,function(err, o){
       if (err) deferred.reject(err);
            deferred.resolve(o);
 });
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
Get({}).then(function(res){console.log(res)});
```

The promise based version seems more complicated to me :).

Comment: Is there anything else I can do? I had that and my code was very messy.

Comment: No, node is asynchronous, and it's either promises or callbacks all the way down:). The callback based code seems elegant to me:)

Comment: It is elegant, but in some part I have to see if there is an error or there is no result in every function with the database I have. But thanks! That solve my question. :)

Comment: Note: Promises have [native support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with Node.js 0.12 and io.js (or via the `--harmony` flag in some previous versions).